# Java default Certificates missing, even if they are in the correct location and I'm not acutally using any

Tags: java, gradle, runtime-error, java-17, cacerts

Any time I run any program that tries to run pure Java code (Coding programs, ENVs and some compiled programs based on it. It does not effect apps that are using Java tho)

For example when I try to run Gradle it gives me an error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Same for other programs

I have uninstalled all jdk and jre files and reinstalled them and changed the JAVA_HOME and Path variable but still it gives me that error. I don't connect to any SSL or other custom servers just the default java ones, so I don't understand why the default certificates in the cacerts file do not work. I think, but I'm not sure, it happened when Java updated. Since then, like 2 months ago, it was like this

Btw I did try to use keytool but it requires a .cer file witch I don't have in Java 17 (to my knowledge)

Here is the trace

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.DownloadUtils.getConnection(DownloadUtils.java:243)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.DownloadUtils.downloadManifest(DownloadUtils.java:307)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.json.Util.getVanillaVersion(Util.java:73)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.actions.ServerInstall.run(ServerInstall.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.InstallerPanel.run(InstallerPanel.java:423)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.launchGui(SimpleInstaller.java:175)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.main(SimpleInstaller.java:147)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 29 more
Failed to download version manifest, can not find server jar URL.
```

Comment: What distribution and version of JDK did you had before the issue and which one do you have now? Have you tried installing a previous one?

Comment: Do you have  in your environment a variable named JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS ? Does it contain something like -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStrore= ?

Comment: Use keytool with the cacerts file. It is a keystore file with password `changeit`.

Comment: I have used jdk 17. No my envs do not contain a variable named JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and how do I use keytool on default cecerts

Comment: Actually I remembered that I have already tried to use keytool but it always required some other file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the registry and windows files. For some reason some program made an unnecessary file in the System32 folder. Just remove the host/hosts and any files named like that from the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc directory and it will be fixed!!!